# Ajax call is not working - Collect Information from merchant transaction page

Tags: c#, ajax

I am new to Ajax. I want to retrieve the transaction details from the merchant website after payment processing. My ajax call script is not working. Please help.

**C# Method**

```
public class RetrieveCache
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string RetrieveTransactionData(string ID)
    {
        ChannelFactory<ServiceSoap> PayChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceSoap>("ServiceSoap12");
        ServiceSoap Paychannel = PayChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        XmlNode node = Paychannel.RetrieveCachedData(ID);
        return node.InnerXml;
    }
}
```

Ajax call Script in HTML Page to call the above c# method

```
Html Page URL: http://localhost:55014/SuccessPage.html?id=29473740923

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = window.location.search;
            debugger;
            var token = (url.replace("?", "").split("=")[1]).toString();
            debugger;
            var dataval = JSON.stringify({ token: token });
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:55014/RetrieveCache.cs/RetrieveTransactionData",
                type: 'post',
                data: JSON.stringify({ token: token }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){

                        alert(data);

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err)
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Does the server side function get called? Does your console window show an error? Does your error portion of your ajax call get hit?

Comment: I am getting the following message on page load... localhost 55014 says: [object Object]

Comment: `console.log(data);` will log it to the Developer Tools console where you can see the entire object tree.

Comment: This is the error message in console: http://localhost:55014/RetrieveCache.cs/RetrieveTransactionData 404 (Not Found)